# Is there a formal name for the effect of searching an item while holding it?

Tags: brain

I've heard some experiences of some friends in which they explained that they started searching an object to then realize that they were holding it. For example, today, a friend of mine told me that he didn't find his phone, so he started searching it and then he realized that it was in his left hand. I'm sure I've also experienced this more than one time.

Is there a formal name for this specific phenomenom? If that's not the case, what would be the closest concept that tries to explain this?

Comment: It might be related to "sensory/neural adaptation," which is the process explaining why e.g. we don't feel the clothes on our body unless we concentrate on them. It's often not stimuli that we perceive, but _changes_ in stimuli. By the time you're looking for your phone, the sensation of holding it has already become ignored background noise, despite being obvious in retrospect. Am interested if this has been academically explored, though.